# How to utilize renderUI and load MathJax manually

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I am building a shiny app with MathJax. However, I need to load the javascript manually because I need the \cancel extension. This works as intended with one exception. I can't get the app to render MathJax with the `renderUI` shiny function. The code below does not display the math as is, but works fine with the usual `withMathJax()` procedure.

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/cancel']},
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['cancel']}}
};
"

out_text <- "Equation 1: $$1+1=2$$"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(async="", src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  uiOutput("main")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$main <- renderUI({
    out_text
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MathJax 3, one has to call `MathJax.typeset()` to refresh the MathJax process. You can add this call in a `tags$script` inside the `renderUI`:

```r
library(shiny)

js <- "
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/cancel']},
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['cancel']}}
};
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(async="", src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js))
  ),
  div("$$1+2=3$$"), 
  div("$$\\cancel{10a}$$"),
  uiOutput("equation")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["equation"]] <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      div("$$\\cancel{10b}$$"),
      tags$script(HTML('MathJax.typeset();'))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```